# Overriding a jQuery Core function in javascript - getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to override the `getJSON` function in jQuery to provide additional params and then call the original `getJSON`. I am fairly unfamiliar with JavaScript and have scraped this together from other similar examples. Most of the examples I have seen override the behavior from a function in the `jQuery.fn` namespace. Could someone help me by telling me what I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($){    
    var _old = $.getJSON;
    $.getJSON = function(){
        alert("Calling overridden getJSON");    
        return _old.apply(this,arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        $(this).getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
            var items = [];
            alert('done');
        });
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        alert(err.message);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `$.getJSON`, not `$(foo).getJSON`;

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
    var items = [];
    alert('done');
});
```