# Modify jQuery getJSON - add functions on call and callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I'm trying to create a loader that tracks when AJAX calls start and end. It's using JSONP so the .ajaxComplete() doesn't work / isn't reliable.

Ideally I'd like to modify getJSON so that every time it is called a function, addAJAX(), is also called. The callback will also fire a function removeAJAX().

Currently I'm having to do this by adding in functions to every getJSON, of which there are many and likely to be many more.

For example:

```
// Add ajax tracker
hl.addAJAX();

$.getJSON('someurl.com?callback=?',{ key: APIKEY }, function(json) {    
  // Remove the ajax tracker
  hl.removeAJAX();
});
```

Creating a wrapper function for AJAX calls is one option, but I'd really like to know if jQuery can be modified this way?

Comment: I was looking to override not modify; I found a getJSON example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052404/overriding-a-jquery-core-function-in-javascript-getjson

Comment: This tutorial helped me do what I needed - monkey patching, or overriding the function: http://encosia.com/adding-your-own-callbacks-to-existing-javascript-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can override jQuery to do such actions. I have posted one answer for a similar type question. So Instead of re-posting, providing the reference -

[How to get default error of ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806040/how-to-get-default-error-of-ajax-call/23806740#23806740)

Comment: Function overriding; I think this is what I'm looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it certainly could be done -- jQuery is just JavaScript, so you could dig through the sources `.js` files, find the method in question and modify to your heart's content. However, this certainly isn't a trivial edit and I would strongly advise you against modifying core functionality of third party libraries unless you think that there's no other feasible option and you're ready for what comes along with it.

I say that because that will mean, among other things, that you'll have to maintain those changes when you're trying to move to future versions, and that you may break support for other libraries or plugins which expect certain functions to work certain ways.

As much as it may be annoying to call the function in the callback every time, that's the recommended way of accomplishing this type of functionality.

Comment: thanks for the reply - yes I don't want to modify the library itself as I can't support the subsequent version upgrade work. I was wondering if hooks or something like jQuery.fn.extend() existed for modifying existing functions in a safe way.